# Como ler um arquivo CSV utilizando Android?

Tags: android, importação

Sou iniciante no Android e estava com dúvidas de como ler um arquivo TXT para a minha aplicação.

Essa pergunta me ajudou bastante:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8499351/how-to-read-csv-file-in-android

Mas no meu caso, o usuário vai colocar um arquivo CSV dentro do sdcard ou da mémoria do tablet , gostaria de saber como eu faço para o usuário escolher onde o arquivo está dentro da memória para poder importar para a aplicação ao invés de fazer minha aplicação procurar um lugar fixo dentro do tablet.

Comment: Na verdade sua pergunta então é: `Como selecionar um arquivo que está dentro da memória do dispositivo?` ?

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que você está querendo criar um explorador de arquivo corre? se for isso de uma olhada nesses 2 artigos esse utilize para ver como mostrar apenas aquivo txt

http://dev-droid.blogspot.com.br/2011/07/recuperando-e-lendo-arquivos-de-um.html

e para criar o explorador utilize esse:

http://custom-android-dn.blogspot.com.br/2013/01/create-simple-file-explore-in-android.html

se der erro ou algo assim tente retirar o componente imagem e suas funções no projeto que da certo, ja implementei usando esses exemplos